# Error with less in Sublime Text 2

Tags: css, less, sublimetext2

I have an error compiling my less file with ST2. I setup these plugins:

```
LESS
LESS build
SublimeOnSaveBuild
less2css
```

And I am trying to compile these example:

```
.generate-columns(4);

.generate-columns(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .column-@{i} {
    width: (@i * 100% / @n);
  }
  .generate-columns(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Expected ')' but found ' ' on line 8 in file '......\public\css\prueba.less':
  [7]:   }
  [8]:   .generate-columns(@n, (@i + 1));
       ----------------------------^
  [9]: }
[Done - Failed]
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code -5]
```

The example is from Less official web: http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature

Can anybody help me please? Is it a bug from plugin?

Thanks a lot, best regards.

Comment: which of the build systems were you using? I think they all come with one, except `SublimeOnSaveBuild`.

Comment: I am using less. It is not checked by default. Everything I have compiled was working, but that example is not working. Thanks.

Comment: It looks ike those ST2 plugins use quite old Less version (below 1.3.3). I'm not sure but I think there're other more up-to-date plugins. You still get this code to compile in Less 1.3.2 end earlier by removing extra parens, i.e.: `.generate-columns(@n, @i + 1);`.

Comment: Thanks seven-phases-max, I installed another plugin and it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to seven-phases-max, I realized that I was using a plugin with old Less version. Finally, everything is working ok with these plugins:

```
LESS
Less2Css
```

And I set Build in automatic. If saving you get this error: "error: less2css error: [WinError 2]", you can install node.js and then run in the terminal "npm install less -g". If you don´t want to install node.js, you can install LESS.js for Windows (https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows) and add it to system path.